# Special formula, term, structure and assignment

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I am trying to find (in a suitable language) a (simple) formula $\phi$, a term t, a structure $\mathcal{M}$ and an assignment b so that for $b':=b_{x/\overline{b}(t)}$ we get a different value for $\hat{b}(\phi[x/t])$ than for $\hat{b'}(\phi)$.

If any notation is unclear, please let me know.

Any ideas on how to approach the problem or any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, your notation is unclear. What does $b_{x/\overline{b}(t)}$ mean? What is $\widehat{b}$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $b_{x/\overline{b}(t)}$ is the assignment b* that fulfills b*(x) = $\overline{b}(t)$ and is equal to b everywhere else. 

And $\overline{b}$ is the unique function that fulfills $\overline{b}(c) = c^{\mathcal{M}}$ for all constant symbols c, $\overline{b}(u) = b(u)$ for all variables u and $\overline{b}(f(t_1, ...,t_n))$ = $f^{\mathcal{M}}( \overline{b}(t_1), \cdots, \overline{b}(t_n)$)} for terms $t_1, ..., t_n$ and a function symbol f.

Comment: Is there anything still unclear?

Comment: I suppose it's unclear to me why you think an example like this exists, or why you want to find one :0)

Comment: @Alex Kruckman My prof. suggested we could try to find an example. But I have to admit that it's possible that none exists. ^^ Do you think so?

Comment: Or do you see a way to show that the values are always equal, i.e. that there is no such example? (Since I've been trying to find one for very long now, I'm not sure anymore that one does exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, we have to prove that $b(\phi[x/t])={b′}(\phi)$ for every $\phi$, i.e. that the operation of assigning denotation to variables commutes with substitution.

We start with $b : \text {Var} \to M$, where $M$ is the domain of $\mathcal M$; thus, $b(x)$ is an object in $M$.

And we have defined $\overline b$ such that $\overline b(u)=b(u)$ for every $u \in \text {Var}$.

Consider induction on the complexity of term $t$ :

*(i)* $t$ is a *constant* $c$.

Then $\overline b(t)=\overline b (c)=c^M$, because $\overline b(c)=c^M$ for all constant symbols.

This means that $b_{x/\overline b(t)}=b_{x/c^M}$, and thus $b'(x)=c^M$.

Consider now the formula $\phi$ with $x$ free.

We have that $b'(\phi)=b_{x/c^M}(\phi)$.

And $b(\phi[x/t])=b(\phi[x/c])=b_{x/c^M}(\phi)$, because the denotation of constant symbols is not affected by variable assignment functions.

*(ii)* $t$ is a variable $y \ne x$.

Then $\overline b(t)=\overline b (y)=b(y)$, because $\overline b(u)=b(u)$ for every variable $u$.

This means that $b_{x/\overline b(t)}=b_{x/b(y)}$, and thus $b'(x)=b(y)$.

Again, if formula $\phi$ has $x$ free, we have that $\phi[x/t]=\phi[x/y]$.

Thus, $b(\phi[x/t])=b(\phi[x/y])=b'(\phi)$.

*(iii)* $t$ is a "complex" term with function symbol $f$.

The proof is straightforward by induction hypothesis and the fact that the interpretation of a function symbol is not affected by variable assignments.

Comment: I see... Thank you, Mauro!

Comment: @Studentu - you are welcome :-)